# How to use CryptoJS with Angular 4

Tags: angular, cryptojs

When I was not using Angular 4, I would just put the `script` tags for the library. Even when I put the `script` tags in the `index.html` file it is not recognizing `CryptoJS`. Is there a way to use the library or a Angular equivalent?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Install using NPM and import below statement in you component file.

```
npm install crypto-js

import * as crypto from 'crypto-js';
```

now you can use crypto in your component file.

Comment: I'd also add `npm install @types/crypto-js` to have types

Comment: this one worked for me on angular 14 **npm install @types/crypto-js**

Answer (score 27):

Use following command to install cryptoJS

```
npm install crypto-js --save
```

You can then build a **AESEncryptDecryptService** service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AESEncryptDecryptService {

  secretKey = "YourSecretKeyForEncryption&Descryption";
  constructor() { }

  encrypt(value : string) : string{
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, this.secretKey.trim()).toString();
  }

  decrypt(textToDecrypt : string){
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(textToDecrypt, this.secretKey.trim()).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }
}
```

In your component, Import & Inject this service

```
import { AESEncryptDecryptService } from '../services/aesencrypt-decrypt.service'; 


constructor(private _AESEncryptDecryptService: AESEncryptDecryptService) { }
```

Use encrypt / decrypt functions

```
let encryptedText = _self._AESEncryptDecryptService.encrypt("Hello World");
let decryptedText = _self._AESEncryptDecryptService.decrypt(encryptedText);
```

Comment: This works! Additionally I had to run `npm i --save-dev @types/crypto-js` for Typescript

Comment: what is the purpose of _self which is use?

Comment: It's been a long time since I posted this code. However, I believe I had assigned the reference of `this` to `_self` because this code was being called in the callback function where I was losing the reference of the class that imported the service.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is at https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/ The import for Angular 6 should be the following:

```
import * as cryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```