# Implementation aes in typescript ionic4 angular

Tags: php, angular, typescript, security, encryption

i know php well but not ts
i have a code in server in php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
define('AES_256_CBC', 'aes-256-cbc');
$encryption_key = ".........";

$iv = ".........";      
$encrypted= str_replace( " " ,"+",$_GET['data'] );

$encrypted = $encrypted . ':' . base64_encode($iv);

$parts = explode(':', $encrypted);

$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($parts[0], AES_256_CBC, $encryption_key, 0, base64_decode($parts[1]));
```

how can i implate it in typescript?

Comment: This can help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Comment: @NehaShah i did not get it how to use to decrypt a input

Comment: @NehaShah would you please give me a example?

Comment: @NahaShah i made service as instruction here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068925/how-to-use-cryptojs-with-angular-4
 but one problem is there is not input for iv also i try to Decryption at here : 
https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption
but it can not work and Decrypt data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57572385/12917651 is a working example and iv will be the value which you want to encrypt like token or anything [ object, array, string]